# ng repeat filter on dynamically created variable

Tags: angularjs, angular

Previously I've used a trick to dynamically generate a variable like this:

```
<div ng-click="showHide=(showHide ? false : true)">toggle bool</div>
<header ng-show="showHide"></header>
```

The code above will generate a local variable called `showHide` that I can use on ng-* attributes. In this case, when the div is clicked, the header is hidden.

Is there a way to create a similar solution for `ng-repeat`'s **filter**, without having to add functionality to the controller (like in the example above)?

In the example below I have a timeline with a bunch of items. I've also got a statistics table over what items exist in this timeline. I want to be able to filter these items by category in the same approach as i did with the `showHide` example.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
<!-- stat table -->
<tr ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.typeOfCategory">
    <td ng-click="filterCategory=(filterCategory ? type.name : '')">{{type.name}}</td>
</tr>

<!-- timeline -->
<div class="timeline-item" ng-repeat="msg in $ctrl.msgs | filter: filterCategory">
<div class="category">{{msg.type}}</div>
</div>
```

So, whenever i click an item in the table, i want the timeline to filter all the other items out. In my mind, `filterCategory`should now contain the value of what `{{type.name}}` is, and filter everything else out.

Is something like this achievable in angular, or am I stretching this technique to its limits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates is own scope, You should define `filterCategory` in controller scope i.e. `$ctrl.filterString` and then use it..

```
<!-- stat table -->
<tr ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.typeOfCategory">
     <td ng-click="$ctrl.filterString=((type.name == $ctrl.filterString) ? '' : type.name)">{{type.name}}</td>
</tr>

<!-- timeline -->
<div class="timeline-item" ng-repeat="msg in $ctrl.msgs | filter: {type : $ctrl.filterString}">
<div class="category">{{msg.type}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I went with this approach myself actually just after i posted this question. I noticed that the dynamically created variable doesn't work in deeper hierarchical code unfortunately. That's mainly the reason why i will accept this as the answer to question. It works, but not what i wanted :( I can update your code to give you the solution i actually used, then mark it as the answer